# Solve a product of binomials raised to a power for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Im trying to solve this equation for x in terms of a, b, c, d, and k:
$k=((a+bx)^b)*((c+dx)^d)$
B and D are positive integers, and A and C are positive or zero and not necessarily integers.  This is for a function in a computer program I am coding.  I'm unsure where to even begin with this problem and have asked several friends who teach math and science and they were unable to make any progress as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try coding a *root finder* algorithm to solve your equation numerically? E.g. consider applying the [Bisection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) or [Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to the function
$$f(x) = (a+bx)^b \cdot (c+dx)^d-k.$$

Note that the root(s) of $f$ are precisely the solution(s) of your equation.

Also note that on most computer systems, such algorithms come in prepackaged libraries. If you describe your computing environment, I can try to help you track down the needed libraries. Alternatively, both methods are very easy to implement yourself directly.

Comment: Thanks for your idea.  Although such a method would work, I'm looking for a more concrete method to find x. I'm creating a program that is capable of solving many different kinds of chemistry problems with high accuracy (x can be as small or smaller than 10^-15).  Also, someone asked me to add this to their TI-84 calculator once I complete the computer version, and there a root finder would be impractical.